# geocomplete is not a function using autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dictionary, geocomplete

Hi i am using autopopulated code getting the error geocomplete is not a function if is used it in locally (seperated file) it works for me what can be the error

```
$(function () { 
    $("#location").geocomplete({
        //alert("gine");
      details: ".geo-details",
      detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
    });

});
```

Pls suggust

Comment: looks like your jquery file is not call over here , Where you write this code ? have you include your jquery file ?

Comment: yes included all jquery files

Comment: ok and its simple core php or you use wordpress ? if possible please post full code

Comment: using simple process it works embedding with zend it doesn't work

Comment: is it trouble with the conflict where do i share it is huge file

Answer (score 3):

You must to add the `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.geocomplete.min.js` before call the `geocomplete()` method:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.geocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#location").geocomplete({
    details: ".geo-details",
    detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
  });
</script>
```